# TFS online conflict: The local changes can not be applied to the target version because they are redundant

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm trying to delete old versions of nuget packages from my solution. I go to the packages dir and I see a lot of old packages that have already been updated.

So I delete them. By app is running fine afterwards.

But when checking in the solution to TFS (Visual Studio Online) I get the old packages back (!)

Deleted them again and went to the Resolve Conflicts screen. There are the old packages. The concflict:

```
The local changes can not be applied to the target version because they are redundant
```

I only have the option 'Take Server Version" but that restores (!) the old package. Strangely the conflict window says

```
local version is 986, Server version is 1020. 
Changes are: local(delete), server(delete).
```

I've try to deleted the packages in a earlier stage.

So why does TFS restores my old and useless Nuget packages and how to check in the solution without having this old packages restored again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds as though you have a pending, delete. run the Server side delete and then get latest. then update your packages. this should clear the issue.

NuGet Packages shouldn't be stored in TFS, you should restore them as part of the build process